# Error 'cannot find type 'UIHostingController' in scope'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Why could a distribution build be failed with SwiftUI?

I added SwiftUI into my iOS 10+ project, and build it locally with `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` prefix, but when I try to build the project for distribution, the build is failed with the following error:

> cannot find type 'UIHostingController' in scope

The same error appears for other SwifUI types in my project (`Text`, `View`, `Font`, etc).

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 17):

The `UIHostingController` type is provided by SwiftUI, not UIKit, so most likely, you need to add `import SwiftUI` to the top of your view controller source file.

Comment: I face this problem too. If you don't import SwiftUI, you can't even compile the code. What the OP has stated is that he is able to build it locally but when building for distribution, the build fails.